# how to correctly version qgis layer using pgversion

Tags: pgadmin

i get an error when trying to use pgversion plugin. I have attempted to add this table to the version db using the pgversion plugin.

has anyone seen this themselves if so can you help with the issue.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "9999"
LINE 5:  '9999-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp ...
^
QUERY:  'create or replace          view '||versionView||'\_time as
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rownum,
to_timestamp(v1.systime/1000)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  as start_time,
CASE WHEN v2.systime IS NULL THEN
'9999-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE
else
to_timestamp(v2.systime/1000)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
END as end_time,
v1.\*
FROM '||versionLogTable||' v1
LEFT JOIN '||versionLogTable||' v2 ON v2.'||myPkey||'=v1.'||myPkey||' AND v2.action=''delete''          and v1.revision \<\> v2.revision
WHERE (v1.action=''insert'' or v1.action = ''update'') and v1.commit = True'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function versions.pgvsinit(character varying) line 214 at EXECUTE

SQL state: 42601
Total rows: 0 of 0
Query complete 00:00:00.129
Ln 1, Col 1
```

im trying to implement versioning of a postgres layer in in qgis using pg admin i expected a view creating in the version schema but get this error